# Rails - How to test a view which needs a Gem instance (f.e. wice_grid)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

I need to write a test for a view file in which we use wice_grid. The problem we have now is that the test fails as the view needs an instance of this.

```
  1) admin/shops/index renders a list of admin/shops
 Failure/Error: render
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   WiceGrid: The first argument for the grid helper must be an instance of the WiceGrid class
 # ./app/views/admin/shops/index.html.erb:40:in `_app_views_admin_shops_index_html_erb___340103790847020275_34309580'
 # ./spec/views/admin/shops/index.html.erb_spec.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The question is: "How can I get an Instance of a Gem to pass it to a view file in the spec?"

**The Test File**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "admin/shops/index" do
  before(:each) do
    assign(:admin_shops, [
      stub_model(Shop),
      stub_model(Shop)
    ])
  end

  it "renders a list of admin/shops" do
    render
    # Run the generator again with the --webrat flag if you want to use webrat matchers
  end
end
```

**This is the view file**

```
<%= grid(@grid, upper_pagination_panel: false) do |g| css_class = 

        g.column name: "Id", attribute: "id"

        g.column name: "Country", attribute: "country_id"

end -%>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Require wice grid in your test:

**Edit: also include wice_grid controller in your test:**

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'wice_grid'

describe "admin/shops/index" do
   include Wice::Controller # this will add the initialize_grid method
   # ...
```

Then in a `before(:each)` in your tests assign the `@grid` var to a new wice_grid

```
describe "admin/shops/index" do
  include Wice::Controller

  before(:each)do
    assign(:grid, initialize_grid(Shop))
  end

  # ... your tests
```

The part where you `initialize_grid(YourModel)` should look the same as what you have in your controller when you assign `@grid` there.

Edit: The way I came up with this was by reading the wice_grid source, starting with this file: https://github.com/leikind/wice_grid/blob/rails3/lib/wice_grid.rb - at line 36 you can see how wice includes itself into `ActionController::Base`. This is how you have the `initialize_grid` method available in your controller. So it should also work for your tests.

Comment: thanks for your answer... the problem i have now is that it says "undefined method `initialize_grid' " because it is a protected method.

Comment: No problem. What do you have in your controller where you instantiate @grid?

Comment: its 

  def index
    @grid = initialize_grid(Shop)
  end

Comment: I edited my answer to include a solution to the undefined initialize_grid error.